# exec() for multi-line string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This works:

```
s = "for x in range(5):" \
    "print(x)"
exec(s)
```

How to add `if` statement to that dynamic code, something like:

```
s = "for x in range(5):" \
    "if x>2:" \
    "print(x)"
exec(s)
```

Above gives error:

```
...
for x in range(5):if x > 2:print(x)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Of course, because the string you generated is **invalid Python syntax**. It will never compile. So just generate syntactically correct code?

Comment: This is invalid Python because you need to include indentation in the string.

Comment: Although, **almost certainly** you shouldnt be using `exec` to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "for x in range(5):\n\t" \
    "if x > 2:\n\t\t" \
    "print(x)"
exec(s)
```

This will solve your problem.
The reason for getting error is ignoring the python indentation rule, so you need to handle them with `\t`.

Comment: Why are you using tabs? Tabs are absolutely **not** required and generally are not recommended

Comment: Tabs are necessary @juanpa.arrivillaga otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: No, it requires some form of *indentation*. Generally, you would use *spaces*, 4-spaces if you follow PEP8, for each indentation level

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because spaces are old-school and tabs much, ___much___ simpler to use - and think of the lots of wasted disk spaces when you compare one byte for a tab with 4 bytes for 4 spaces.

Comment: yes for spaces are equal somehow to `\t`. :)

Comment: @Programmer wasted disk space? Is disk space some sort of precious commodity?  In any case, [the official style guide uses spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, ok go on and start to count how many spaces you have added and don't use tabs.

Comment: @A.Najafi I am certain it is inconsequential. You can use whatever you want but know that the standard is 4 spaces

Comment: The [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using spaces.

Comment: @martineau I want to know whoever wrote that PEP. If I'd been his boss, I would've thrown that PEP directly into the waste bin.

Comment: @Programmer: The authors are listed near the top of the first page if you had bothered to read any of it. One happens to be [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), creator of the Python programming language — perhaps you've heard of him.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the lack of proper indentation of the code in the string. An easy way to get it right is to enclose the properly formatted code in a triple-quoted string.

```
s = """
for x in range(5):
    if x>2:
        print(x)
"""
exec(s)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Programmer: And luckily for you, it'll work with tabs or spaces for indentation as long as you're consistent.

Comment: Sadly you can't type tabs on SO.

Comment: @Programmer: It's probably at least partially due to PEP 8. I believe the reason spaces are preferred is because there's no universal standard that specifies how many spaces each one is equal to. According to Wikipedia the original de facto standard was at every multiple of eight characters horizontally, but many folks preferred tabs of 4 for their code. Spaces **do** have the same size in mono-spaced typefaces, universally.

Answer (score 1):

note that `\` is only python's way of allowing visually continuing the same declaration at a "new line". so in practice,

```
s = "for x in range(5):" \
    "if x>2:" \
    "print(x)"
```

is equal to

```
s = "for x in range(5):if x>2:print(x)"
```

You will need to add actual line breaks and tabs to make the syntax valid, as such:

```
s = "for x in range(5):\n\tif x>2:\n\t\tprint(x)"
```

note that you can make it more readable if you combine `\` with the above, and swapping `\t` with spaces, resulting in:

```
s = "for x in range(5):" \
    "\n if x>2:" \
    "\n  print(x)"
```

(Note that to [confirm with PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), you should use 4 spaces per identation)

Comment: tabs are *not necessary* and indeed, not recommended.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - indeed, but for 1-liner, I think it is a must if you want it to be somewhat readable. I adjusted the multi-line version.